# Unable to run while loop related to regular expressions in vbscript running through Windows based script host

Tags: regex, vbscript, wsh

I am attempting to learn regex syntax in VBScript by running CurrencyEx.vbs from the following link: 
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx

However, the code runs into a compilation error 'Expected identifier' at line 10, character 13, Code: 800A03F2.

```
do while re.
```

Any suggestions to run a 'while' loop for a regex object would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spurious line break:

```
do while re.Test(inputstr) <> true
```

**Added:**

The last `)` in the pattern

```
\s*((\$\s?)|(£\s?))?((\d+(\.(\d\d)?)?)|(\.\d\d))\s*(UK|GBP|GB|USA|US|USD)?)\s*$
```

is not matched.

The pattern allows "$ 1.23 UK".

Thou shall not try to learn from code that compares boolean expressions against boolean constants.