# Dysfunctional inputbox method in vbscript being run through wscript.exe on command prompt

Tags: regex, vbscript, wsh

I am attempting to learn regex syntax in VBScript by running CurrencyEx.vbs from the following link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx

I fixed the error on line 10 as shown on this query:
[Unable to run while loop related to regular expressions in vbscript running through Windows based script host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34663887/unable-to-run-while-loop-related-to-regular-expressions-in-vbscript-running-thro/34664016#34664016)

Now this script doesn't meet its intended purpose as I don't see a dialog box returned by the inputbox() method on line 6 for inputting custom text:

```
inputstr = inputbox("I will help you convert USA and CAN currency. Please enter the amount to convert:")
```

The script ends with an exit code 0 in vbsedit.exe. I cannot figure out my mistake, so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Post the rest of the code that surrounds this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the script starts with

```
Sub CurrencyEx
Dim inputstr, re, amt
Set re = new regexp  'Create the RegExp object

'Ask the user for the appropriate information
inputstr = inputbox("I will help you convert USA and CAN currency. Please enter the amount to convert:")
...
```

and you "don't see a dialog box returned by the inputbox() method on line 6", I think you didn't add the call of the Sub to your program. So pre/ap-pend a line

```
CurrencyEx
```

to the script.